# How to change default listening port on webbserver IIS 7?

Tags: ssl, port, https, iis

How do you change the default port to which the webbserver IIS 7 is listening for incoming traffic to whatever portnumber?

e.g.
I have web application named "mywebapplication" published on SSL port 444.

```
https://mywebapplication:444/
```

I wish access to this application with the url:

```
https://mywebapplication/
```

(without specify the custom port number)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

The port being connected to is determined by the client, not the server - the client in this case is the web browser being used to access your site.  Port 80 is always the default for `http`, and port 443 is always the default for `https` - you cannot change this.

If you want to be able to connect to this service with `https` without entering a port number explicitly, the service must be listening on port 443.

Comment: Very good explanation!